# Is there a function in xarray to help compare two variables over time, and account for missing values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, netcdf, python-xarray

I am trying to compare the temperature values from two different xarray datasets over a year (we'll call them temp1 and temp2), by subtracting temp1 from temp2 to see how different they are. I am then plotting the differences using a standard matplotlib scatter plot. The xarray datasets are organized by day. I am able to open the xarray datasets, extract the temperature variables from each of them, and then subtract temp1 from temp2 (and create plots) to get what I need.

Trouble starts when temp1 has, for example, 1440 values (one for each minute of the day), but temp2 only has 1300. Temp data for the missing 140 values in these cases are simply not present in the dataset (ie, there is no missing value indicator).

How do I account for instances like these? I don't want anything to be plotted when temp1 has a value at a particular time, but temp2 does not (or vice versa).

Here is the error that I get: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (42771,) (43198,)

Comment: I think you need another information to align these two arrays. I mean, you need to align the two arrays that every sample in temp1 relates to the corresponding element in temp2. Because otherwise, we don't know temp1[10] corresponds to temp2[?]. There should be a timestamp information to align them. After aligning, You can set all missing elements with some special value and then subtract, then plot the difference. But to not plot for missing values you can set a filter.

Comment: please provide sample dataFrames. (temp1, temp2)

Comment: temp1: <xarray.DataArray 'temp_mean' (time: 42771)>
dask.array<shape=(42771,), dtype=float32, chunksize=(1440,)>
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2018-01-01 ... 2018-01-30T23:59:00
Attributes:
    long_name:            Temperature mean
    units:                degC

temp2:
<xarray.DataArray 'atmospheric_temperature' (time: 43198)>
dask.array<shape=(43198,), dtype=float32, chunksize=(1440,)>
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2018-01-01T00:00:05 ... 2018-01-30T23:59:06
Attributes:
    long_name:      Dry bulb temperature
    units:                degC

Comment: can you write a short program to reproduce this error with data?

Comment: @Hamed already gave you a good answer how to proceed. I would just add that usually, when I am comparing two time-series, I interpolate them to some common time-axis and so I get two series with the same length. For instance, if the target time-axis is based on the common time values in both of the series, the interpolation just selects the values from original series at certain time moments.